# addClass to an element with that class already?

Tags: jquery

If I were to call addClass on an element that already had the class I was adding, such as:

```
<div id="lolID" class="lolClass"></div>
```

and then:

```
$("#lolID").addClass("lolClass");
```

Would this cause problems or just do nothing?

Same for removeClass but reversed.

Comment: The class will not be added twice. Likewise, if the specified class does not exist on the element, removeClass does nothing.

Comment: What kind of problems do you think it could have? Even if an element could have the same class twice, I don't see how this should have any influence on selectors. An element either has a class or it doesn't.

Comment: @Felix Kling: What kind of benefit do you think asking that could have?

Comment: @landons: Understanding the OP's thought process.

Comment: You guys are silly for trying to close a legitimate (albeit, easily answered) question.

Comment: someone tried to close my question?!?!! it doesnt say in the documentation so id say its legitimate

Comment: I didn't vote to close but I'd argue that you could have just tried this and see if you got any problems with whatever you intended to do.

Comment: That's true, but then we'd all actually have to work on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: Although it is always good to ask questions, I would also suggest you to do some testing yourself first and try to figure out before asking. In that way you will learn faster instead of just waiting for an answer from someone.

Comment: There are some problems that arent that easy to spot, just making sure

Comment: This is a good question - it actually asks about the redundancy - it is not in the manual and if jQuery wouldnt do it for you it would cause problem... Fortunately it jQuery wont addClass if already hasClass :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nope.  No effect.  jQuery handles that for you.

Comment: I'll be here all week.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; such calls will have no effect:

Answer (score 0):

Not in jquery, but in javascript you could (for what reason you would do that, well i don't know):

http://jsfiddle.net/LdtNy/

```
var elem = document.getElementById("lolID");
elem.className = elem.className + " lolClass";
```

This will have no effect at all.

Comment: Annnd, you could do it in the html: `<div class="lol lol lol lol lol">`

Comment: all the week you said... Well, good point

Comment: Well, that doesn't mean much; I'm really just trying to kill 2.5 hours. Trollolol

Comment: You have demonstrated that it is possible to add a class multiple times, but you haven't answered *"Would this cause problems or just do nothing?"*.

Comment: @FelixKling That was specifically in reference to calling the jQuery methods.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery checks if the class is already added to the element,
if so it will just ignore the function