# is there any harm in adding a class to an element that already has that class using .classList

Tags: javascript, css

This question's answer ([addClass to an element with that class already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864542/addclass-to-an-element-with-that-class-already)) indicates that when using jQuery there is no problem that arises if you `.addClass('foo')` on an element that already has a class of `foo`.

I am curious of the same is true for the `element.classList` method of `.add`.

In particular I have a function called `update()` that is called whenever a range slider is updated. This can occur many times a second. Depending on the value passed to `update()` I add and remove certain classes to an element.

If the value falls in a certain range consecutively I end up adding the same class over and over again.

My question is can I allow  `elem.classList.add('foo')` to run, let's say, 50 times in one second without experiencing any negative consequences to user experience, memory, processor use, etc.  Is this an acceptable practice?

Thanks.

Comment: It is "fine", although might represent code to tidy-up. Class names cannot be duplicated in the HTML DOM element-class attribute, as such represents a set. This is the same as if a class is duplicated in the HTML markup: it would be automatically de-duplicated.

Comment: Did you try it to see what happens?

Comment: Yes it seems to work fine. I am simply curious if there are any hidden reasons why this is not a best practice.

Comment: it is fine, that is what the `classList.add()` is for ;)

Comment: "Acceptable" is entirely up to you and whatever organization you are writing code for.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## DON'T do this:

```
if (!el.classList.contains("foo")) {
    el.classList.add("foo");
}
```

## DO this:

```
el.classList.add("foo");
```

## Reason:

- The `.classList` property is a [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) object.
- It represents a **set** of whitespace-separated tokens.
- The tokens (i.e. the class names) are case-sensitive.
- The term "set" in programming refers to a container that holds a **unique** collection of items, in unspecified order.
- In other words, a set cannot contain duplicates.
- The DOM specification which defines the `DOMTokenList` defines it as a container with case-sensitive, whitespace-trimmed, **unique** items.
- All methods that **read** or **modify** the `DOMTokenList` (such as `DOMTokenList.add()`) automatically trim any surrounding whitespace and remove duplicates from the set.
- Meaning that if you try to `add()` the same className twice, it won't add the duplicate.

Here's an example:

```
<span class="    d   d e f"></span>

// Output: DOMTokenList(3) ["d", "e", "f", value: "    d   d e f"]
// As you can see, it only contains the unique values.
console.log(document.querySelector("span").classList);

// Try to add a duplicate value.
document.querySelector("span").classList.add("e");

// Output: DOMTokenList(3) ["d", "e", "f", value: "d e f"]  
// As you can see again, it only contains the unique values.
console.log(document.querySelector("span").classList);

// In fact, the act of duplicates being detected while trying
// to add more classes, results in the "class" attribute itself
// being cleaned up and trimmed:
// Output: "d e f"
console.log(document.querySelector("span").getAttribute("class"));
```

Alright, so why, exactly, shouldn't you use `.contains()` to "avoid calling `.add()` when unnecessary"? Because:

- The `.contains()` function and the `.add()` functions use the exact same native code for searching through the unique set to see if it contains the class.
- Therefore there's no speed difference between their techniques for detecting whether a className exists.
- In other words, calling `.add()` will search through the set, and if it already contains the className, the function simply aborts. And yes, it *sometimes* also cleans up the "class" HTML attribute if necessary, but only if necessary.
- On the other hand, if you call `.contains()` before `.add()` and you end up adding the className, you just ran the search for the className twice, via two different functions.
- But more importantly: You make your code clunky and unreadable by having that huge `if (!el.classList.contains("foo")) { ... }` boilerplate around every attempt to add classes.
- The DOM spec was made to be modern and performant for the use-cases programmers need it for. That means, that you **should** be using `.add()` to add a class (even if it already exists), and `.remove()` to remove a class (even if it's already missing).

Don't waste your keyboard's life and programmer eyes on clunky boilerplate. Only use `.contains()` if you actually care about finding out if an element has a certain class.

#### Also keep in mind that the `DOMTokenList` has many other helpful functions:

- See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList.
- `.replace(oldToken, newToken)`: Replaces an existing token with a new token. If the old token doesn't exist, `.replace()` returns `false` immediately, without adding the new token to the token list.
- `.toggle(token [, force])`: Removes a given token from the list and returns `false`, or if token doesn't exist it's instead added and the function returns `true`. Alternatively, if you include the `force` parameter: If included, turns the toggle into a one way-only operation. If set to `false`, then token will only be removed, but not added. If set to `true`, then token will only be added, but not removed.
- Those two extra functions will let you implement most of things you'd ever wanna do instead of "if not .contains() then .add()" or similar code. You should ONLY be using ".contains()" if YOU personally need to know if a token exists.

Comment: Agreed, its also more pythonic, for those of us who are python coders

Answer (score 0):

While no harm will be done, you would be better off wrapping it like so:

```
if(!elem.classList.contains('foo')) elem.classList.add('foo');
```

Comment: Given that adding a duplicate class-name results in that duplicate not being added, why is it better to use the `if`, what benefit does it offer?

Comment: It's more intentional. I may be off base with saying that is best practice, but a lot of linters and companies have standards about being intentional and literal with the logic for things like these.

Comment: Interesting thought. What about stress on system resources? Is wrapping it in an conditional going to increase or reduce compute time?

Comment: I would bet that it would not have an effect on system resources or compute time because with out the "if" in there, the system will do something similar in order to ensure the properties of a set.

Comment: Mitch McMabers makes a compelling point, which is that internally, `contains` and `add` call the same code. So on the one hand you have semantic intentionality when calling the code twice, but on the other hand doing so violates the DRY principle under the hood. I prefer not to use `contains` for that reason.